# Breadcrumbs in C# MVC Website using Bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I'm looking to add breadcrumbs to my site, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I have been able to get something basic working with the following code:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="active">
        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
        @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] != "Home" && ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] != "Index")
        {
            @:> @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), "Index", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
        }

        > @ViewBag.SubTitle
    </li>
</ol>
```

The problem I have though is that this doesn't actually track your history, it just shows you

```
Home > ControllerName > CurrentItem
```

e.g.

```
Home > Members > Greg Dodd
```

This works well when you've come from a member search page, however if you come from a different page then you lose that history. How do you create a breadcrumb trail using History in MVC?

I guess what I'm looking for is something like:

```
Home > Controller1 > PreviousItem > ... > CurrentItem
```

e.g.
If you opened up a blog, then a particular blog item, then clicked the authors name, your breadcrumbs should be:

```
Home > Blog > SomeBlogTitle > AuthorName
```

If however you opened a list of authors and then chose a particular author, you would see the same view rendered using the same controller, but the breadcrumbs should show:

```
Home > Authors > AuthorName
```

Comment: Have you tried [MvcSiteMapProvider](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider)?

Comment: I looked at it, but couldn't see how to use it to do what I'm after. I can't map every object in a dynamic database. Is there a tutorial showing how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

If you want a simple solution you can use this code. It is just for default routing configuration.

> Home / Controller / Page

```
  @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower() != "home")
  {
       <ol class="breadcrumb">
             <li>
              @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
             </li>
             <li> @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), "Index")
             </li>                                
             <li class="active"> @Html.ActionLink(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString())
             </li>                                                       
        </ol>
   }
```

Comment: Greate solution! With a little bit more CSS/Bootstrap it looks really good! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/

Answer (score 7):

I created an OSS project to solve the problem for myself. I needed more dynamic control of the label in the breadcrumb:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcBreadCrumbs

or, contribute here:

https://github.com/thelarz/MvcBreadCrumbs

Comment: Please dont just post links in here but post the code helping the opener to solve his/her problem.

Comment: Ok so the fact that I wrote an entire solution to the problem installable into his app with nuget was simply inadequate. Got it.

Comment: @Larz he means post some of the code snippets as well.

Comment: Note that this package is under the GPL. This means that if you include it in your project, you must also license the rest of your project under the GPL.

Comment: If you take your project down, this answer will become meaningless.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problems please? Open an issue if possible.

Answer (score 6):

after install that via nuget :

```
PM> Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider
```

then you can put this line in your Layout:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false, true, true)
```

also you can customize it to fetch data from data base, first you need create a class that derives from `DynamicNodeProviderBase` :

```
   public class PostDetailsDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
    {
        private readonly IPostService _postService;

        public PostDetailsDynamicNodeProvider()
        {
            _postService = new PostService(new MyDbContext());
        }

        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {
            var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

            foreach (var post in _postService.GetSiteMapData(20))
            {
                var node = new DynamicNode
                {
                    Title = post.Title,
                    Controller = "Post",
                    Action = "Index",
                    Area = "",
                    LastModifiedDate = post.ModifiedDate

                };
                node.RouteValues.Add("id", post.Id);
                node.RouteValues.Add("title", node.Title);
                returnValue.Add(node);
            }

            // Return 
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

GetSiteMapData :

```
public IList<SiteMapModel> GetSiteMapData(int count)
        {
            return _posts.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(post => post.CreatedDate).Take(count).
                          Select(post => new SiteMapModel
                              {
                                  Id = post.Id,
                                  CreatedDate = post.CreatedDate,
                                  ModifiedDate = post.ModifiedDate,
                                  Title = post.Title
                              }).ToList();
        }
```

then change MvcSiteMap file in your project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd"
            enableLocalization="true">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="">
    <mvcSiteMapNode clickable="true"  title="" dynamicNodeProvider="yourCustomClassNamespace" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm still missing a piece of the puzzle. What does GetSiteMapData(int) look like?

Comment: it's a method that return an anonymous type instance using `select new ` that we need to use them in `DynamicNode`, check the answer now.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. I want a browser history to show me where I came from, not a history of the last 20 blog posts which is what I think this is getting me

Comment: Just figured out that it doesn't work for MVC 5. It creates the breadcrumbs, but if I'm view a post/article it won't show the breadcrumb...

Comment: any license tied to this? open to use for every developer?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">


        @if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() != "Home")
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
            <li class="active">
                / @ViewBag.Title
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li class="active">
                Home
            </li>
        }

    </ol>
```

Work for you with bootstrap

Answer (score -2):

For MVC 5 you have to use: Install-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5